# How to log http request and response using box-java-sdk?

Tags: java, json, logging, box

I'm troubleshooting an issue where the code seems to provide an error when ran on a different machine. I've tried setting the following but I do not see log output.

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
Logger.getLogger("com.box.sdk").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
```

I'm really interested in seeing the request and response in JSON format to compare.